# Firebase cloud messaging push not reaching chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a `FCM` push message to a Chrome service worker. I have the id for FCM registration of the Chrome browser.

I get a Status `200 (OK)` response when I send the message from  Postman ( a tool to send requests to REST API, equivalent to curl command). But this Push message never reaches the service worker on Windows PC. I tried to replicate this on Android Chrome , and it gets the Push message.

Push messages for PC on Chrome were reaching till this afternoon, and then suddenly stopped. I am trying to read the Push notification event in the Service Worker like below -

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Received a push message', event)
});
```

Also, I tried to debug if my code had a problem, and used Chrome developer console to simulate a Push event, and it was able to detect the same and execute rest of the code. Hence, my best guess is FCM messages for my app are somehow getting blocked.

Comment: We're seeing the same issue.

Comment: any solution???

Comment: It got fixed automatically. Most likely an issue with your account. I had contacted Google support team, although they could not find any issue on my account or on FCM side, it got fixed automatically the next day. I suspect some temporary issue on FCM side.